# How can i make a element that can be clicked only once?

Tags: javascript, html

I started javascript not long ago  and i made a simple Tic-tac-toe game. But when i click a box twice, the o and the x show. I would like to show only one. If my code isnt clean, feel free to tell my how to clean it up a bit. I can give you the html code if you need it. Thanks for the time your maybe gonna take to help me.

```
let case1 = document.getElementById('case1');
let case2 = document.getElementById('case2');
let case3 = document.getElementById('case3');
let case4 = document.getElementById('case4');
let case5 = document.getElementById('case5');
let case6 = document.getElementById('case6');
let case7 = document.getElementById('case7');
let case8 = document.getElementById('case8');
let case9 = document.getElementById('case9');

let i = 0;
let oui = 0;

case1.onclick = function(){
    if (i== 0){
        document.getElementById('un').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('deux').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
    case1.onclick.removeAttribute();
};

case2.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('trois').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('quatre').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};

case3.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('cinq').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('six').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }

};

case4.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('sept').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('huit').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};

case5.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('neuf').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('dix').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};

case6.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('onze').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('douze').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};

case7.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('treize').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('quatorze').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};

case8.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('quinze').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('seize').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};

case9.onclick = function(){
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById('dixsept').style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById('dixhuit').style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
};
```

here is the html

```
  <body>
    <div id="contener" style="display: flex; position: relative;">
        <div class ="case" id="case1"><i id="un" class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="deux"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case"id="case2"><i id="trois"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="quatre"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case3"><i id="cinq"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="six"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case4"><i id="sept"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="huit"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case5"><i id="neuf"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="dix"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case6"><i id="onze"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="douze"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case7"><i id="treize"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="quatorze"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case8"><i id="quinze"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="seize"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
        <div class ="case" id="case9"><i id="dixsept"class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i id="dixhuit"class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What is the HTML? You have a *lot* of IDs for some reason

Comment: In your current implementation, you seem to have your `removeAttribute` executed incorrectly. It should be `case1.removeAttribute("onclick");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i changed it but its not working

Answer (score 1):

i dont have a solution for you but some tipps for the code. I can give you a solution if you post the html aswell :). Nonetheless here are my tipps for better code:

1. Probably use a counter and modulo instead of adding and subtracting, example:

```
if (++i % 2){
  document.getElementById('trois').style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById('quatre').style.display = "block";
}
```

2. It would be nicer to solve it with one function which works for all the cases by just passing the dom-object to the function which was clicked. I dont know your HTML but probably you can give the elements better names aswell so you can dynamically find them. Example ids would be `box1-cross` or `box1-circle`.

EDIT:

So after i saw the html, you should just use classnames on the circle and cross elements. You can find the elements by using a query selector: `case1.querySelector('.cross')`.

the final solution could look like this:

JS:

```
let counter = 0;

    document.querySelectorAll('.case').forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (c.classList.contains("set")) return;
      c.classList.add("set");
      if (++counter % 2) {
        c.querySelector('.circle').style.display = "block";
      } else {
        c.querySelector('.cross').style.display = "block";
      }      
    }));
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="contener" style="display: flex; position: relative;">
    <div class="case" id="case1"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case2"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case3"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case4"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case5"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case6"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case7"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case8"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
    <div class="case" id="case9"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x circle"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x cross"></i></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, what happens when put (++i % 0) ?

Comment: Sorry it has to be `++i % 2`.

++i increments variable i(before the the line is executed).
i % 2 means give me the rest which results by devide by two. So on every odd number it will be 1 and on every other number it will be 0. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you take to help me :)

Comment: You are welcome, if you are statisfied feel free to give me an upvote :P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all the IDs, add a click listener to the *container*, and if the clicked element was a `.case`, navigate to the inner `<i>` and turn its `display` on, if no `<i>`s have already been set to `display: block`:

```
// This is the *entire* Javascript you need:
let player = 0;
document.querySelector('#contener').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // e.target is the clicked element
  // .closest navigates to the nearest ancestor matching the passed selector
  const caseDiv = e.target.closest('.case');
  if (!caseDiv|| caseDiv.querySelector('i[style]')) {
    // If the click wasn't inside a case,
    // or if the case already has a descendant <i> with a style, don't do anything:
    return;
  }
  // this selects the appropriate child <i> element inside the caseDiv
  const i = caseDiv.querySelectorAll('i')[player];
  // this sets the style of that <i> to block
  i.style.display = 'block';
  // this inverts the "player" variable from 1 to 0, or vice versa
  player = 1 - player;
});
```

with HTML of:

```
<body>
  <div id="contener" style="display: flex; position: relative;">
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
    <div class="case"><i class="far fa-circle fa-10x"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-10x"></i></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Im still pretty new to Js, i dont really understand whats happening in that code. Im going to look a bit into it or maybe if you have some time could you maybe comment the code a bit more ? If its not to much to ask.

Comment: Ok, I added more comments

Comment: You may consider upvoting or accepting any of the answers, if they helped you

Answer (score 1):

- Clear entirely your HTML. No IDs needed, no `<i>` needed.
- FontAwseome already provides a `font-family`. Use it.
- Assign a class to the clicked element, `"o"` or `"x"` (deepending on whi plays first in the `pl` variable)
- Use `Element.addEventListener()`
- Use `Element.removeEventLietener()`

```js
let turn = 0;                             // 0=Circle, 1=Cross (starts first)
const ox = ["o", "x"];                    // Class to added on click depending on turn
const els = "<div class='case'></div>".repeat(9);
const play = ev => {
  const el = ev.currentTarget;            // Who was clicked
  el.classList.add(ox[turn]);             // Add the respective class
  el.removeEventListener('click', play);  // No more clicks! thx
  turn = ++turn % 2;                      // reset turn to 0 if reaches 2
                                          // < Winner game logic goes here
}

document.querySelector('#contener').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', els);
document.querySelectorAll('.case').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', play));
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#contener {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 150px;
}
.case {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.case.o:before { content: "\f10c"; }
.case.x:before { content: "\f00d"; }
```

```html
<div id="contener"></div>
```